# How can I create a method in order to sum the columns from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I can't figure out how to create a method in order to sum the columns from the array once it has been created. Rows and columns are created randomly, but im trying to add up each column at the end. Method in my code is called sumTotal, any suggestions please? Thanks!

```
public static void printMonths(String[]months){
    for (int i=0; i<months.length; i++)
        System.out.printf("%-20s", months[i]);
}
public static void startSales (double[][] array){
    for (int row=0; row<array.length; row++)
        for (int col=0; col<array[row].length; col++)
            array[row][col] = (int)(Math.random()*10000);
}
public static void printSales (double [][] array){
    for (int row=0; row<array.length; row++){
        for(int col=0; col<array[row].length; col++)
            System.out.printf("L. %10.2f    ", array[row][col]);
        
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void repeat (char c, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        System.out.print(c);
}
/* public static void sumTotal(double[][]array){
    for (int i=0; i<row.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<col.length; j++)
            System.out.println("");
    }      
}*/

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner inputNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner inputText = new Scanner(System.in);
   String name;
   int rows = 10;
   double total;
   String [] months = {"January", "February", "March"};
   
    System.out.print("Type complete name: ");
    name = inputText.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Type number of rows: ");
    rows = inputNumber.nextInt();
    if (rows>0){
        double[][] sales = new double [rows][3];
        
        startSales(sales);
        
        System.out.print("\nSales Report\n\n");
        System.out.print("Salesman: " + name + '\n');
        System.out.println();
        
        repeat('=', 60);
        System.out.println();

        printMonths(months);
        System.out.println();
        
        repeat('=', 60);
        System.out.println();
        
        printSales(sales);
        repeat('=',60);
        
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not executed and compiled the code but the following code may give you a head start.

**Version 1 (Get sum of specific column)**

```
public static int sumTotal(double[][] array, int col)
{
    int total = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        total += array[i][col];
    }
    
    return total;
}

int sum = sumTotal(myArray, 3); //sum of only column 4 starting from 0 index
```

**Version 2 (Get sum of all columns)**

```
public static int[] sumTotal(double[][] array, int totalcols)
{
    int[] total = new int[totalcols];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < total.length; i++)
    {
        total[i] = 0; //initialize to 0
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < total.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            total[i] += array[j][i];
        }
    }
    
    return total;
}

int[] sum = sumTotal(myArray, 6) //6 is the total columns count you will get 1D array of sum of 6 columns
```